# WMI - two way authentication

Tags: windows, security, authentication, wmi, wbem

I've been unable to find this information on MSDN. How can I implement two-way authentication for WMI (or, if that is not possible, using Windows' implementation of WBEM?).

What I want to accomplish is for the client to authenticate the server, and the server authenticate the client via certificate exchange, irregardless of the user credentials.

Comment: What you want is not directly possible with WMI (which is MS implementation of WBEM). However, I created a work-around that could be used to accomplish this. Let me know if you want me to post link to method.